# How to remove loop array values in nested foreach?

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, foreach

#### Note: I am Using jkanban.js plugin for drag and drop that's why I need to get the result in json format

## This is my code

```
//Declare global empty array
$nodes = [];
$docs = [];

foreach($getStations as $key => $step){
   foreach($docs as $key=>$val) {
       $docs[] = array(
                    "id" =>"$val[0]",
                    "title" => "$val[2]",
                    "class" => "color$color"
                );
   }//second foreach

  $nodes[] = array(
    "id"=>"step_ID",
    "title"=>"Some Title",
    "class"=>"Some Class",
    "item" =>$docs //Pushing the array $docs
);
}//end main foreach

//Display the result
echo json_encode($nodes);
```

### This is the screenshot of the result

The number inside parenthesis is the total items

[image: The number inside parenthesis is the total items]

### What I want is to get rid of the loop result of array docs inside nodes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Declare your variable inside your first loop, if you attempt to push your second loop.

```
$arr1 = array();
foreach(){
    $arr2 = array();
    foreach(){

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

### This works now

by declaring the variable $docs empty array inside the first foreach loop...thanks to marjameson

```
 //Declare global empty array
$nodes = [];

foreach($getStations as $key => $step){
  //Declare docs empty array
   $docs = [];

   foreach($docs as $key=>$val) {
       $docs[] = array(
                    "id" =>"$val[0]",
                    "title" => "$val[2]",
                    "class" => "color$color"
                );
   }//second foreach

  $nodes[] = array(
    "id"=>"step_ID",
    "title"=>"Some Title",
    "class"=>"Some Class",
    "item" =>$docs //Pushing the array $docs
  );
}//end main foreach

//Display the result
echo json_encode($nodes);
```